# Calculator small exponent gives zero

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, applications

When I try to do the following calculation using Calculator app I get 0.

```
$E=N_A\frac{h\cdot c}{\lambda}$
```

where `N_a` is Avogadros number `6.022x10^23 mol^{-1}`, `h` is Planck's Constant `6.626 x 10^-34 Js`, `c` is the speed of light `2.998 x 10^8 ms^-1`and `\lambda` is the wavelength of light, so lets say `400 x 10-9 m`

I should get `299 kJ mol-1` but Calculator gives me a big fat 0.

If I input Planck's Constant and try a simple operation on it it returns 0.

Obviously the issue is with small exponentials but they are not equal to 0!

Am I overlooking something obvious?

Comment: math way outside my league, but Calculator is only good to 15 decimal places, afaik.

Comment: The Calculator app in iOS8 can handle it though! Strange anomaly! Maybe a feature request for Yosemite 10.10.next_one or whatever pat of the U.S. they decide to call it.